# Condense multiple rows into one sum row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to condense all rows with Quantity <=500 into one row entry that sums them together

```
SELECT c.CompanyName
, d.NumNameCode
--, CAST((d.Quantity*10) as INT) as Quantityx10
, SUM(CASE
      WHEN Quantity <=500 THEN CAST((Quantity*10) as INT)
      ELSE ''
  END) as '<=500'
,  CASE
      WHEN Quantity > 500 THEN CAST((Quantity*10) as INT)
      ELSE ''
   END as '>500'
FROM [TFBO7].[dbo].[CustInv] ci
  inner join [TFBO7].[dbo].[Cust] c
  on c.CustomerID=ci.CustomerID
  inner join [TFBO7].[dbo].[CustIDet] d
  on ci.TransactionID=d.TransactionID      
WHERE ci.TransactionDate between '2010-07-01' and '2010-07-30' and d.TransactionTypeID='1' and NumNameCode LIKE '%gov%'
  group by NumNameCode, CompanyName, Quantity
  order by NumNameCode, '<=500'
GO
```

My table looks like this

```
 CompanyName    NumNameCode       <=500     >500
 DESC           JET A*Gov Army      0        5030
 DESC           JET A*Gov Army      0        7140
 DESC           Jet A*Gov Army      0        7940
 DESC           Jet A*Gov Army    680          0
 DESC           Jet A*Gov Army    710          0
 DESC           Jet A*Gov Army    860          0
```

I need to condense the entries that are <=500 into one summed row

```
 CompanyName    NumNameCode       <=500     >500
 DESC           JET A*Gov Army      0        5030
 DESC           JET A*Gov Army      0        7140
 DESC           Jet A*Gov Army      0        7940
 DESC           Jet A*Gov Army      0        2250
```

Comment: what should the output look like?

Comment: you can use what you have as a sub query and select an outer query the sum of those columns you have in the list and group by NumNameCode and CompanyName, and Sum the <=500 and >500 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your code, you have `group by` on `quantity` and hence it is grouping all unique quantities which is leading to your issue. You can use a subquery as suggested in earlier comment or do a simple `Union` like this:

```
SELECT  CompanyName
      , NumNameCode
      , SUM(CASE WHEN quantity <= 500 THEN CAST(( quantity * 10 ) AS INT)
                 ELSE ''
            END) AS '<=500'
      , NULL AS '>500'
FROM    #temp2
WHERE   quantity < 500
GROUP BY NumNameCode , CompanyName
UNION ALL
SELECT  CompanyName
      , NumNameCode
      , NULL '<=500'
      , CAST(( quantity * 10 ) AS INT) '>500'
FROM    #temp2
WHERE   quantity >= 500
  GO
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure! Glad it helped. If this answered your question, just hit the tick mark to the left of the answer, unless of course you are waiting for more suggestions.